# Edit users in database using sql

Tags: php, html, sql, database, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to generate a table of all user accounts and then have buttons next to each user to either delete or change the account level of the user (admin or not admin). What would be the best way to go about this?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  user_name,user_id,user_email,user_level
                    FROM users
                    ORDER BY user_name ASC");

echo '<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-default">
      <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Options</th>
       </tr>
       </thead>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

  echo '<tbody>
         <tr>
           <td class="col-3">' .$row['user_name'].'</td>
           <td class="col-3">' .$row['user_id'].'</td>
           <td class="col-3">' .$row['user_email'].'</td>
           <td class="col-3">' .$row['user_level'].'</td>  
           <td class="col-3"><a class="btn btn-success" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Promote"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Demote"></span></a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
           </td> 
          </tr>
          </tbody>';
       }
   echo '</table>'; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Edit: The admin/standard user is set via user_level with 0 being standard user and 1 being admin

edit 2: Added code

```
    <?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_level='1' WHERE user_id='".$_GET['user_id']."'");
die("User promoted to admin.");

include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Getting no luck with it, will try to add if statements for feedback on if database row changes

Comment: People couldn't help you with this without knowing what the database structure looks like.  What are the possible values of `users.user_level`, for example?

Comment: The values for user_level are 1 & 0. With 1 being admin and 0 being standard user. Tried using the code you sent below and editing it to the the structure I have but still no luck

Comment: mysql_* is Deprecated and should not be used in new code, and you  are open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Johnny Are you sure you're connecting to the database correctly?  What error are you getting?

Comment: No error messages, connecting to database correctly as I use the same connect page throughout the whole site

Answer (score -1):

Without full details, it would be something like this:

```
 <a class="btn btn-success" href="promote.php?id='.$row['user_id'].'" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Promote"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></a>
 <a class="btn btn-danger" href="demote.php?id='.$row['user_id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Demote"></span></a>
```

Then you need a `promote.php` in the same directory as this file, which would look like this:

```
<?php
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_level='1' WHERE user_id='".$_GET['user_id']."'");
die("User promoted to admin user.");
```

And a `demote.php` like so:

```
<?php
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_level='0' WHERE user_id='".$_GET['user_id']."'");
die("User demoted to standard user.");
```

Answer (score -1):

This here is example of code, because your questions lack some details, so i am sharing my code.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>User Email </th>
<th>Date & Time </th>
<th>Complain Number</th>
<th>Complain Type</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Status</th>

</tr>
<?php 
$ccount =1;

$email= $_SESSION["email"];
$query = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from new_complain where new_email = 
'$email'");
while($rows = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
 ?>
<tr>

<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'sstd' . $ccount ; ?>" value="<?php 
echo $rows['complain_type']; ?>" placeholder="Student Name" />
<td><?php echo $_SESSION["email"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['complain_date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['new_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['complain_type']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['new_complain']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['comlain_status']; ?></td>

 </tr>

<?php 
  $ccount++;
   } ?>
</table>
```